# Python - Tkinter - canvas.move not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a bunch of objects that have a tag, and while the canvas.find method returns the IDs for the all the object as expected (see the print call near the bottom), the canvas.move command doesn't move the objects.

I build a test script that performs as I expect, so I know the method is in theory sound.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import * 
master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=1000, height=1000)
w.config(bg='white')
box=25
startX=100
startY=800
rows = 5
columns = 6
coords=[[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]]]
widths=[[2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2]]
tagsList = [["a","a","a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a","a","a"]]
for j in range(1, 7):
 for i in range(1, 6):
  coords[j-1][i-1]=[(startX)+(box*(j-1)),(startY)+(box*(i-1)),(startX)+(box*j),(startY)+(box*i)]
colours=[["white","#660000","#863030","#ba4a4a","#de7e7e","#ffaaaa"],["white","#a34b00","#d46200","#ff7a04","#ff9b42","#fec28d"],["white","#dfd248","#fff224","#eefd5d","#f5ff92","#f9ffbf"],["white","#006600","#308630","#4aba4a","#7ede7e","#aaffaa"],["white","white","white","white","white","white"]]
w.create_text(startX+(box*columns)/2, startY-(box/1.2), text="Key:", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 20),tag="key")
w.create_text((startX-(box*1.5)),(startY+(box*(rows-1)/2)), text="No. \nDroids", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tag="key")
w.create_text((startX+(box*columns)/2,(startY+box*(rows))+(box/1.5)), text="No. Sigs", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tag="key")
w.create_text((startX+(box*(columns-4))-box/2,(startY+box*(rows-1))+(box/1.9)), text="5", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #5
w.create_text((startX+(box*(columns-3))-box/2,(startY+box*(rows-1))+(box/1.9)), text="4", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #4
w.create_text((startX+(box*(columns-2))-box/2,(startY+box*(rows-1))+(box/1.9)), text="3", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #3
w.create_text((startX+(box*(columns-1))-box/2,(startY+box*(rows-1))+(box/1.9)), text="2", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #2
w.create_text((startX+(box*(columns))-box/2,(startY+box*(rows-1))+(box/1.9)), text="1", justify = "center",font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #1
w.create_text((startX+box/2,(startY+box*(rows-5))+(box/2)), text="1", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #1
w.create_text((startX+box/2,(startY+box*(rows-4))+(box/2)), text="2", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #2
w.create_text((startX+box/2,(startY+box*(rows-3))+(box/2)), text="3", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #3
w.create_text((startX+box/2,(startY+box*(rows-2))+(box/2)), text="4", justify = "center", font=("Helvetica", 16),tags=("key", "b")) #4
for i in range(0, 5):
 for j in range(0, 6):
  w.create_rectangle(*coords[j][i],width=widths[i][j],tags=(tagsList[i][j],"key"),fill=colours[i][j])   
w.tag_raise("b")
w.move(w.find_withtag('key'), 500, -250)
w.pack()
print str(w.find_withtag('key')) 
w.update()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [Tkinter Canvas Widget documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method), the argument passed into the move command is the same as the [find_withtag](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method) tag. So you should be able to simply change the code to this:

```
w.move('key', 500, -250)
```

Comment: I understand that, thats why I used `print str(w.find_withtag('key'))` to demonstrate that the tags are being collected by `w.find_withtag`

Comment: RE: your edit - Yupe. That works. How frustrating. How did you know that the tag is addressed directly, and not indirectly (the way I was trying)? Thank you.

Comment: Which I did...  What I didn't get was that an 'Item specifier' is not the ID number, but a tag - had the doc said that, I would have known!... I'm not complaining, I'm trying to learn, and curious what lead you to know that the tag was a specifier. (Given that in a test I did, my method worked for a few items...). As I said, I really appreciate your help - I've been trying to get this running for a few hours :(

Comment: @JayGattuso: No problem. I've been many times in your situation, so I well understand;-) Sometimes some things just aren't clear to everyone, and it takes a different perspective to clear it up.

Comment: @Jay Gattuso: tkinter documentation can sometimes be a bit incomplete. Tkinter is a wrapper around the tk toolkit which is very well documented, and the translation from tcl/tk to Tkinter is usually trivial. For definitive documentation you might try reading the official tk docs at http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm In the canvas documentation there is a section on what is a valid identifier, including a sentence saying you can use a tag name or an actual id.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that w.find_withtag('key') returns a tuple object, but w.move expects an individual integer id (or a tag string)

You could do:

```
for id in w.find_withtag('key'):
    w.move(id, 500, -250)
```

While in your case, using simple 'key' is better, if you had an arbitrary list of ids, you would need to loop though them instead of passing it in.